# Redirect with inactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My objective is to keep a user in a view as long as he/she keeps clicking a button within a certain lapse.

I'm using Rails and was exploring a solution via an embedded JS in the pertinent view.

So far I'm able to set a time after which the user will be redirected to root path with the following script:

```
var delayedRedirect = function (){
  window.location = "/";
}

var delay = 10000;

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', delay);
});
```

I've been trying to write a function that resets the value of 'delay'or that calls the setTimeoutFunction again.

```
$('#btn-persist').click(function() {
  delay = 3000; 
 // or calling again setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', delay);
});
```

But I noticed that changing the variable won't affect the setTimeout function that has already been called.

I've also tried to use the clearTimeout function as below without success

```
var delayedRedirect = function (){
  window.location = "/persists";
}

var delay = 3000;

var triggerRedirect = function() { setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', delay); 
}

var stopRedirect = function (){
  clearTimeout(triggerRedirect);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  triggerRedirect();

  $('#btn-persist').click(function() {
    stopRedirect();
  });
});
```

I wonder why this may not be working and if there's any other way to stop the execution of the setTimeout function that has already been called so I can call it again to effectively reset the time to the original value of 'delay'.

At the same time, I don't want to stop any other JS functions that are running in parallel.

Do you see a better solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem why clearTimeout is not working. because you are clearing a anonymous function instead of a setTimeout variable

change this

```
var triggerRedirect = function() { setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', delay); 
}
```

to this

```
var triggerRedirect = setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', delay);
```

Edit:
also change this (if you want to restart the inactive redirect trigger)

```
$('#btn-persist').click(function() {
    stopRedirect();
  });
```

to this

```
$('#btn-persist').click(function() {
        stopRedirect();
        triggerRedirect();
      });
```

Comment: Of course, thanks! That's why it's not working. Thanks